# console app behaviour in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I'm just trying to see if my Qt creator is running properly, what happens is when I create a new project in Qt and I choose Qt console application and I change the main to:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

then it runs with no errors but the console window just appears for less than a second, just flashes once and closes. Is that normal or is it supposed to wait for me to press a key to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's normal, there's no activity happening so it creates the application, does no lines of code then returns a 0 and exits.

Comment: how would I get it to stay there like it does in c++

Comment: It doesn't in C++. If you removed the Qt include there and rebuilt it you'd see much the same behaviour of it starting and disappearing as there's no code. If you want it to wait for input or similar remember to include `iostream` and use `cin`.